# How to fix output error with "##.# M' in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

When trying to get an output of "#.## M" I receive an error, but when I remove the M, I do not. Having the M at the end is imperative to the end result. Formatting alone outside of the formula does not work.

I've tried several web searches that did not fix the issue. I don't know what else to attempt.

```
=(TEXT('National Economy & Finance'!C13, "#.## M"))
```

I expect an output of 42.42 M but instead receive the following error:

> Invalid format pattern '#.## M' in TEXT evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the M:

```
=(TEXT('National Economy & Finance'!C13, "#.## \M"))
```

"#.##" would be interpreted as a decimal number and "M" would normally be interpreted as month, so you can't have both together in the same format.

You can also just put

```
=(TEXT('National Economy & Finance'!C13, "#.##"))&" M"
```